# Only a limited number of rows in my excel sheet can be plotted on Highchart

Tags: excel, highcharts, limit, rows

I am parsing an excel sheet which has 250 rows of data. However my highchart highstock chart would only show data if I limit my file to 40 rows or so..Why?

Additionally, it always defaults to 3m. How do I force the default viewing to be other value let say 1Y?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have many points so please increase [turboThreshold](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.turboThreshold) parameter